# How to scroll through an iframe using playwright( javascript)?

Tags: iframe, scroll, playwright

I have a web application that has an iframe. The iframe has a scroll bar.  I am using playwright for automation. Is there a way to scroll through the inframe using playwright? Both web application and iframe belong to 2 different URL's.

I tried  the below suggestion from one of the answered questions, but it did not work.

`var myIframe = page5.frameLocator('#t-abcd') myIframe.onload = function () { myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(100,100) }`

Comment: It's very hard to help without the site and a [mcve] of your code. Every site has unique behavior making it impossible to look at a single line like this and be able to identify a working solution. That said, I can say that adding `onload` to a Node Playwright element doesn't make sense--that should run in the browser inside an `evaluate()` (although no guarantee that that'll achieve the result you want, only that it at least makes logical sense and the code will actually be executed).